# JQDateRangeSlider change bounds issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with the DateRangeSlider for the first time and I'm using it as a TimeSlider: [FiddleJS](http://jsfiddle.net/Dana15/LJrYf/151/)

The problem is that when a button is pressed the min bounded value, or the max one, should change, but it doesn't do anything for min or broke the slider when pressing the button for max.

The default values are for January 1st:

```
var minDateStr = "2014-01-01T00:00:00Z";
var maxDateStr = "2014-01-01T23:59:00Z";
```

to display the hours:minutes for one day and the button bounded values are from January 5th:

```
min :new Date("2016-01-05T05:00:00Z")
```

Is there a way to change the min and max bounds properly to "2016-01-05T05:00:00Z" without changing the default values (January 1st)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if the task you're trying to achieve is practical or is even possible.

- [According to the documentation](http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/options.html#defaultValuesOption), slider values can be changed by code only at initialization. It means that even if you set either `min2` or `max2` to either end to the bound, then the slider can't "jump" there to properly represent the area you've originally selected. This is not practical.
- Moreover, in the documentation, I couldn't find any way to get the values at which the labels are "standing". Apparently, `min2` and `max2` are not modified but serve rather as regular and unmodified JS constants.

You **can** modify the bounds but if you desire to do so, you have to use HTML inputs for dates. It doesn't seem to be possible by defining new bounds with the selected range.

Comment: You are right. I have a Datetimepicker from witch comes the different day and time, depending on the users selection. I think the best option for it will be just to keep the selected time but change the day according to the default values because only the time is displayed. But, if the user will want to change from a small time range to a larger one, will this be possible?

Comment: @Dana try asking this question on [User Experience SE](ux.stackexchange.com), I think they can provide a much better solution than I ever would.